# Pass an Intent Action to running Service

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service

I have a running `Service` and I have a `BroadcastReceiver` and an `Activity` that interacts with said `Service`.

Basically, when the `BroadcastReceiver#onReceive()` activates, it calls the service so `onStartCommand()` will trigger. When called by this component, the service should just change a `boolean` value form `false` to `true`

When the `Activity` calls the `Service`, it also should change another `boolean` value from `false` to true.

In order to identify where is the `Service` being called from, I pass a custom action via the `Intent` like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
intent.setAction("change_boolean_1_to_true");
startService(intent);
```

And then, in the `Service` I do:

```
String action = intent.getAction();
    if(action != null) {
        Log.d(TAG,"Action found"); .......
```

But the `Log` doesn't print anything, which means the action is comming null.

My question would be:

1. Is it appropriate to pass an Intent Action to do this?
2. Why is it not working?